# Absolute paths for the include and library directories when cmake with flag CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE

Tags: cmake, nextcloud

Can you help me with this problem?
I configured the client build when built NextCloud (Owncloud) in desktop client. I cloned git://github.com/owncloud/client.git and created sub-dir named client-build. I got an error when typed "cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" .." in MinGW

```
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (project): The CMAKE_C_COMPILER: cl is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
```

I set path for g++ and c in MinGW. Link here: https://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/2.3/building.html#generic-build-instructions

Comment: The error message is specifically about **compiler path**, any of the listed in the title has nothing common with the error. Build instructions explicitely tells to use `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"` for build for MinGW. But your log shows that you build for `NMake Makefiles`.

Comment: I suspect you don´t have a compiler installed in MinGW/MSYS. Does calling `gcc --version` give anything? Otherwise call `mingw-get install gcc`.

Comment: Have you specified the generator on the cmake cmdline: cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles"?